# Добавление картинок на ViewGroup

Tags: android, activity

Создал `LinearLayout`, в котором разместил 3 картинки. Приложение вылетает. Когда 2 картинки, то все работает. В чем может быть проблема ? 3 картинки располагаются на `LinearLayout`, который вложен в еще один `LinearLayout`(в самом низу 3 `ImageView`).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_first_activity"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:shadowColor="#ff0000"
    android:shadowDx="7"
    android:shadowDy="7"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:text="Welcome!"
    android:textColor="#FFFF00"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/emailView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:padding="8dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passwordView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:padding="8dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRegistration"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_style"
    android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_black"
    android:text="Регистрация"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#3498db"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAuthorization"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_style"
    android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_black"
    android:text="Авторизация"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#3498db"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:typeface="normal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="69dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/burger"
            android:rotation="-20"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/cake"
            android:rotation="-5"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/meat"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

```
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:747)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:568)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1014)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3747)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3620)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1852)
    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:408)
    at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:463)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:203)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
    at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:59)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:732)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.coursework.EmailPasswordActivity.onCreate(EmailPasswordActivity.java:32)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, логи ошибки из Logcat.

Comment: @YungBlade добавил

Comment: вообще, если я не ошибаюсь, подобные ошибки возникают из-за того, что используются  изображения слишком большого разрешения.
Попробуйте прописать в AndroidManifest.xml, в теге <application> строчку android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: Или, лучше, использовать картинку меньшего размера. Google не рекомендует использовать `largeHeap`

Comment: @YungBlade прописал, приложение запустилось, но картинка не отобразилась

Comment: @Jarvis_J а какого размера лучше использовать картинки ?

Comment: Понятно, что чем меньше, тем лучше. Конкретной рекомендации нет, зависит от необходимого качества изображения. Я, например, стараюсь не выходить за размеры 600х800, по возможности 400х600. Плюс рекомендую использовать Glide/Picasso для кэширования изображения.